# Puzzled about java and how to make it run in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: java

Coming from Windows and .NET development world, I'm trying to migrate to Ubuntu 12.10 and JAVA development world but I'm getting very confused about:

- What is the most standard form to install JAVA EE JDK? Should I download and run the shell script from Oracle, use the packages at WebUpd8 PPA or install the OpenJDK packages?
- What are the differences between Oracle's JAVA and OpenJDK's JAVA? Can I think of them as like Microsoft's .NET and Mono Project's .NET?
- I've installed Oracle's JAVA using the shell scripts but how can I get the browsers to run JAVA Applets? I've installed IcedTea Java Plugin but i'ts working only in some sites, others are halting Firefox.
- By the way, what exactly are the IcedTea Java Plugin? It's a JAVA runtime implementation by its own or it is using the Oracle's JAVA that 'ive installed like some kind of bridge to teach the browser how to get to the runtime?

This transition isn't easy as I expected. Afff!
I appreciate any help!

Comment: This is several questions, only peripherally related. I recommend asking them separately.

Comment: Agreed, Eliah Kagan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the most standard form to install JAVA EE JDK? Should I download and run the shell script from Oracle, use the packages at WebUpd8 PPA or install the OpenJDK packages?

> Oracle JDK (for using PPA you can use this command **sudo
>   add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java** )

What are the differences between Oracle's JAVA and OpenJDK's JAVA? Can I think of them as like Microsoft's .NET and Mono Project's .NET?

> Open JDK is an open source project, whereas oracle JDK is a
>   proprietary product (previously known as Sun JDK), go with Oracle JDK,
>   its been used as standard at many places.

I've installed Oracle's JAVA using the shell scripts but how can I get the browsers to run JAVA Applets? I've installed IcedTea Java Plugin but i'ts working only in some sites, others are halting Firefox.

> currently remove your installed plugins and install through **Synaptic
>   package manager** (select **oracle-java6-installer**) it will install everything that you need for development (jdk) and runtime (jre)

By the way, what exactly are the IcedTea Java Plugin? It's a JAVA runtime implementation by its own or it is using the Oracle's JAVA that 'ive installed like some kind of bridge to teach the browser how to get to the runtime?

> You can get your answer here :
>   http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

I found out that following this http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-jre-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-ppa/ method the JDK installation is super easy, on the other hand if you want to have a powerfull IDE let me recommend you NetBeans, it´s really solid and has very good debuging tools.

Answer (score 0):

There was a project in the works called "Apache Harmony" (recently shelved) where all of Java's code was going to be open sourced. Generally Java is open-source friendly but there are differences between OpenJDK and the official java runtimes. I do believe Oracle themselves now use the OpenJDK projects as the basis for commercial releases of Java, much like the way Google uses Chromium as the basis for Chrome.

There's some interesting history about that in this article: 
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/11/13/open_sourcing_java_five_year_anniversary/

I think the way forward that will be the most efficient and comfortable for you would be to install the official java runtimes and plugins until compatibility is greater or you get more familiar with OpenJDK, but you can still run a nice open source IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans.